# How do I put a bunch of NSIntegers into an array?

Tags: objective-c

I had three variables of NSInteger type, the question is how do you put the NSInteger in an array or data set?

```
- (void)someNumber {
    NSInteger one   = 1;
    NSInteger two   = 2;
    NSInteger three = 3;

    // how do you put the NSInteger in an array or data set？
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? What does "NSInteger of group" mean? Do you simply want to put your three variables in an `NSArray`? Why is the return value of `someNumber` set as `id`? You really need to clarify your question. Please [edit] your question with all clarifications. Do not post comments.

Comment: You are asking to return multiple values from a function like Swift `Tuple`. But it is not possible in objective c and you have to use `NSArray` or other collections.

Comment: I am so sorry that, sometime you have some NSInteger type, I want to put some NSInteger variables into a data set. so do you have good idea?

Comment: You can only put `(NS)Objects` into a `NSArray`. The simplest way is then to use `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the `NSInteger` as `NSNumber` in `NSArray` like bellow

```
- (void)someNumber {
    NSInteger one   = 1;
    NSInteger two   = 2;
    NSInteger three = 3;

    // how do you put the NSInteger in an array or data set？
    NSArray *numberGroup = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberwithInteger:one],[NSNumber numberwithInteger: two],[NSNumber numberwithInteger: three]];
}
```

Comment: That's the same suggestion as in zoul's answer but with a much more cumbersome syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make an `NSArray` of them?

```
NSArray *all = @[@(one), @(two), @(three)];
```

This boxes them into `NSNumber` objects using the `@` operator.